# How to find the source of memory contention?

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, profiling, jstack

I've written a program to do some parallel computation, like so:

```
public void multiThreadedRun(int nThreads) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread [] threads = new Thread[nThreads];
    // create and start nThreads ...
    for (int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i) {
        // ... where each thread runs a task-grabbing loop in this::work.
        threads[i] = new Thread(this::work);
        threads[i].start();
    }

    System.out.println("all threads started, waiting for them to finish....");
    for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; ++i)
        threads[i].join();
    System.out.println("all threads finished.");
}
```

Running this program on a c5.24xlarge EC2 instance, with 96 cores and 192GB of memory, using
`java -Xms150g -Xmx150g -XX:+UseParallelGC` (using AWS's Corretto jdk), I've timed the execution of the above `multiThreadedRun` method with `nThreads` equal to 1, 8 and 96. The run times were (fairly consistently): 285, 63, and 42 seconds, respectively.

So, *8 threads give a 4.5x speedup, and 96 threads give only a 6.8x speedup, compared to the single-thread run. How can I figure out what's limiting the speedup?*

I believe the contested resource is memory because

a. This is a compute task which does not initiate any I/O, and should fit easily in the 150GB allocated to the heap (so I don't expect much virtual memory I/O).

b. When running on 96 threads, I've called `jstack <pid>` every couple of seconds and pooled the results (for the 96 threads executing `work()`): 1844 of the samples found a thread in "RUNNABLE" state, and only 76 found it waiting for a monitor. So it *seems* that not much time is spent waiting on locks (but perhaps `jstack` has a sampling bias? or maybe there's some other problem with this approach to rule out lock contention?).

Assuming this is indeed a memory issue, **how do you go about diagnosing the source of the memory contention?**

More specifically:

- Will "differential profiling" (comparing where time is spent in an nThreads = 96 run and an nThreads = 1 or nThreads = 8 run) be useful? Note I'm *not* asking how to use profiling to speedup my code - rather I'm trying to understand if comparing the profiling results can help figure out where memory contention lies - and how.
- Are there tools for seeing how much time different variables spend in each cache layer, and what triggers cache flushes?
- I have some guesses as to which objects cause the memory contention. Is there some way to test such hypotheses?

Comment: This code is running in a machine with how many cores?

Comment: @dreamcrash this is a 96 core machine (or more precisely, this is an EC2 instance that *should* behave like a 96 core machine...)

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/c5/ (c5.24xlarge is somewhere near the middle)

Comment: They do have a comparable "bare metal" instance, I can try that but it's often harder to get...

Comment: Thanks for the info, I added the tag multithreading so that more pick can have a look at your question

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look with perf and see what your CPUs are doing. If the CPU's are contending for memory, they should have a low IPC because they will be stalling on memory access. You could have a look at toplev to drill down to where time is actually being spend without getting lost in metrics.

Another trick you could apply it to sun the same process with a fixed number of threads. So 1 process only, 2 processes, 3 processes etc. And see how well your system scales. If the processes would be CPU bound I would expect an almost linear performance increase till you are hitting 50 cores or so.

PS: Make sure your program runs long enough because the JIT needs time to warm up. So make sure you run at least a few minutes.